# rendering xml and html tags in a code snippet HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

simply,how to render code snippet with `<html>` tags like this

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header_area"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header"  /></div>
   <div id="body_area"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></div>
   <div id="sidebar_area"><tiles:insertAttribute name="sidebar" /></div>
   <div id="footer_area"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /></div>
</div>
```

i found this code.but it adds endtag to all `/>`

```
function encodePreElements() {
    var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
    for(var i = 0; i < pre.length; i++) {
        var encoded = htmlEncode(pre[i].innerHTML);
        pre[i].innerHTML = encoded;
    }
};

function htmlEncode(value) {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   var text = document.createTextNode(value);
   div.appendChild(text);
   return div.innerHTML;
}
```

so above code will be like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header_area"><tiles:insertattribute name="header"></tiles:insertattribute></div>
    <div id="body_area"><tiles:insertattribute name="body"></tiles:insertattribute></div>
    <div id="sidebar_area"><tiles:insertattribute name="sidebar"></tiles:insertattribute></div>
    <div id="footer_area"><tiles:insertattribute name="footer"></tiles:insertattribute></div>
</div>
```

`.innerHTML` renders correctly in javascript `alert`. so how can i render code snippet like first? what is the easy way to do this process?

Comment: You don't have any `pre` tags in your sample xml/html

Comment: Why do you use that `htmlEncode` function? Just set `.innerText = .innerHTML` (or equivalent with textnodes)

Comment: In what format do you get those HTML snippets? Are they strings, already parsed DOM nodes, results of an Ajax request?

Comment: they are string stored in the db

Comment: In which db, a clientside one? Or how do you get them to the client where the Javascript is executed?

Comment: no its server side mysql.i need to get all source inside `pre` tag.

Comment: Which serverside language do you use - it is certainly not javascript + jQuery, is it?

Comment: first i put java `string` to the page div using EL.after that i call above js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17119/discussion-between-bews99-and-bergi)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I assume that in your question, the first quoted block is embedded inside a `<pre>` element, like this:
`<pre>
    <div id="container">
        ...
    </div>
</pre>`

And you are trying to convert that so that it becomes:
`<pre> &lt;div ... </pre>`

The problem is that when the page is loaded, the contents of `<pre>` is *loaded into the DOM*.  When you get the value of `pre[i].innerHTML`, it returns you a value that accurately represents the DOM state, but is not the same as your original HTML.

If you want to preserve the exact HTML used in the page, you need to *encode that HTML when you generate the page*.  By the time any JavaScript has access to the content, it's too late - the original HTML is gone, and all you have left is the DOM contents.